# If-else statment not working after else is added

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write a search fnction for an address book which loops through the array of contacts and shows them in a popup. It first worked fine finding and showing the found contacts. After adding the else statement, only "none found" runs. I've tried switching the order and negating the first statement, but that does not work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
newSearch.click(function(){
  const inputValue = $('#searchcontacts').val();
  for(let i = 0; i < contactList.length; i++){
      if(inputValue.toUpperCase() === contactList[i].firstName.toUpperCase()){
        resultsContent.text(contactList[i].firstName +
          " " + contactList[i].lastName +
          " " + contactList[i].phoneNumber +
          " " + contactList[i].addressText);
    } else {
   }
  };
  resultsContent.text('None found')
});
});
```

Comment: where is your html? and this is not full `js` you added

Comment: You call `resultsContent.text()` outside your for loop at the end so no matter what you set before that you are going to be overwriting it. Also note in the actual loop each call to `.text()` is going to overwrite the previous.

Answer (score 1):

You have always set the `resultsContent.text('None found')` after for loop is executed.
So even if a contact found and that contact is set to the `resultsContent`, it will be replaced by the `resultsContent.text('None found')` line

Following code snippet will do the job for you. But I have seen another issue with this code that only the last found contact will be shown in the `resultsContent` element since you have not accumulated the found results. If you need to show all the contacts you need to accumulate all of them and show

```js
newSearch.click(function(){
  const inputValue = $('#searchcontacts').val();
  var hasContacts = false;
  for(let i = 0; i < contactList.length; i++){
      if(inputValue.toUpperCase() === contactList[i].firstName.toUpperCase()){
        resultsContent.text(contactList[i].firstName +
          " " + contactList[i].lastName +
          " " + contactList[i].phoneNumber +
          " " + contactList[i].addressText);
          hasContacts = true;
    } else {
   }
  };
  if( !hasContacts) {  
    resultsContent.text('None found');
  }
});
```